# Is it possible to have constant value for a javascript object?

Tags: javascript

I am beginner with javascript and I try to stick to good programing practices, like the use of constants for values that don't change.

For example, I would like to store the settings in a constant:

```
const settings = {};
settings.backgroundColor = '#FFF'; 
settings.textColor       = '#333'; 
settings.shadowColor     = '#DDD';
```

I noticed that even though "settings" is a constant, I can re-assign other values later during the execution of the program for example I can reassign values here without triggering errors:

```
settings.backgroundColor= '#FFF';
if ( test === 1) {
    // my block of code
}
settings.backgroundColor= '#F00';
settings.backgroundColor= '#00F';
settings.backgroundColor= '#123';
```

This code is valid and the console does not throw any kind of error.

Is there a solution to have real constants stored inside my object "const settings"?

I tried this but it did not work:

```
const settings = {};
const settings.backgroundColor = '#123';
const settings.textColor       = '#333'; 
const settings.shadowColor     = '#DDD';
```

It throws an error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'settings' has already been declared"

This question is not very important since my code works properly, I just try to have good practice of development.

Thank you for the help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved by using passing the object to the `Object#freeze` method.

From MDN [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze):

> The `Object.freeze()` method freezes an object. A frozen object can no
> longer be changed; freezing an object prevents new properties from
> being added to it, existing properties from being removed, prevents
> changing the enumerability, configurability, or writability of
> existing properties, and prevents the values of existing properties
> from being changed. In addition, freezing an object also prevents its
> prototype from being changed. freeze() returns the same object that
> was passed in.

```js
const settings = {};
settings.backgroundColor = '#FFF'; 
settings.textColor       = '#333'; 
settings.shadowColor     = '#DDD';

Object.freeze(settings)

settings.textColor = "#FFF";
console.log(settings)

settings.newColor = "#FFF";
console.log(settings)

delete settings.textColor
console.log(settings)
```

Note - The operations above throws `TypeError` in *strict mode*

The above method makes a shallow freezing of the object, but any child object property can be modified:

```js
const obj1 = {
  internal: {}
};

Object.freeze(obj1);
obj1.internal.a = 'aValue';

console.log(obj1.internal.a)
```

To freeze the entire object graph you need to freeze individual object properties of the object recursively:

```js
function deepFreeze(object) {
  // Retrieve the property names defined on object
  const propNames = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(object);
  // Freeze properties before freezing self
  propNames.forEach(name => {
    const value = object[name];

    if (value && typeof value === "object") {
      deepFreeze(value);
    }
  });
  return Object.freeze(object);
}

const obj2 = {
  internal: {
    a: null
  }
};

deepFreeze(obj2);

obj2.internal.a = 'anotherValue'; 
console.log(obj2.internal.a)
```